# JFrame getRootPane() Returns Null

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings, keystroke

In my main class I initially start out by creating the java frame. Later I create a new object from another class entitled 'keybinding' and pass it the JFrame. It then applies the action maps for certain keys to the *root pane* of the JFrame.

I was previously writing this application in the educational IDE BlueJ where this code worked fine. But I'm in the process of moving it to regular IDE, in this case JDeveloper. All the code works apart from the this keybinding.

With the below code, using JDev, calling getRootPane() returns null.

Stage.java

```
jf = new JFrame("The Title");
jf.setSize(800,600);
//etc
Keybinding keys = new Keybinding(this);
```

Keybinding.java

```
KeyStroke pressLeft = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");
stage.jf.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                          .put(pressLeft, "pressLeft");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to the KeyBinding class should just be

```
new KeyBinding(jf);
```

Then the code in the KeyBinding class can access the frame as follows:

```
public KeyBinding(JFrame frame)
{
    JRootPane rootPane = frame.getRootPane();
    rootPane.getInputMap(...)
}
```

Comment: Passing it a pointer and making it use that to reference the JFrame is indeed silly when I could just pass it the JFrame to begin with, thanks. I don't see why that route still shouldn't work however?